# apache htaccess strip string from url

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

H
I have a url like this

```
http://www.example.com/my-beautyfull-url-12345,some%20shit%20i%20dont%20need%20and%20i%20dont%20know%20why%20is%20here
```

in .htaccess I want to get rid of everithing after the comma (including the comma actually). atm I am using something like that

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+-|)([0-9]+)(,.+)(/)?$
```

but id doesn't work.

thanks
M

Comment: `RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]*),(.*)$ /$1` ?

Comment: that works, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]*),(.*)$ /$1
```